# Assembler code doesn't work on Linux

Tags: linux, assembly

I'm trying to run the following assembler code in Linux using the JWasm compiler. But for all commands, it says, command not found. Why? And it returns an error in the lines which starts with ";". Is it a kind of a comment line? Can I remove this lines? Thanks.

```
;--- "hello world" for 64-bit Linux, using SYSCALL.
;--- assemble: JWasm -elf64 -Fo=Lin64_1.o Lin64_1.asm
;--- link:     gcc Lin64_1.o -o Lin64_1


stdout    equ 1
SYS_WRITE equ 1
SYS_EXIT  equ 60

.data

string  db 10,"Hello, world!",10

.code

_start:
mov edx, sizeof string
mov rsi, offset string
mov edi, stdout
mov eax, SYS_WRITE
syscall
mov eax, SYS_EXIT
syscall

end _start
```

Comment: Sounds like the OP is trying to execute the source file as a shell script?

Comment: Do you have any idea of how should I fix it? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with JWasm, but generally un-indented entries are assembler directives and not instructions.

You want to place a (space/tab) for any actual assembler instructions (things the CPU would run), not assembler directives (things the assembler uses to help you out)

Comment: in the file its indented, just here that its not. What assembler compiler do you use for linux? GCC compiles it?

Comment: @psyhclo: I always just use `gas` (the GNU assembler) on Linux.

Comment: I installed it, but, how to start it? I typed ./configure, make. And it installed a bunch of things, but how to make it compile files??

Answer (score 0):

; usually denotes comments in most kinds of assembly, strange that JWasm doesn't recognize the lines as such. Try removing them.

Comment: I removed the ';'. But it dont recognizes the commands. For any command of the program, JWasm says command not found. 

I dont know if it is the model of the assembler, because the linux assembly code is different from the windows assembly code. But i've tryied with an assembly code for linux, even that way, JWasm dont recognizes.

Did you used JWasm already??

Comment: I downloaded JWasm and it compiled just fine; **Lin64_1.asm: 24 lines, 2 passes, 0 ms, 0 warnings, 0 errors**

Comment: how did you configured it? I pasted the folder jwasm in home folder and I access it by doing this in the terminal:

cd jwasm
./jwasm
cd Samples
./Lin64_1.asm

and then it returns this


./Lin64_1.asm: line 1: sintatic error near `token' not waited `;'
'/Lin64_1.asm: line 1: `;--- "hello world" for 64-bit Linux, using SYSCALL.

have any idea of why it can be happening? thanks.

Comment: The directions for compiling it _are in the file_: **;--- assemble: JWasm -elf64 -Fo=Lin64_1.o Lin64_1.asm**